# como acceder a un elemento dentro de un objeto react

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, filtro

que tal? tengo dos tablas (Tabla checkInError, Tabla checkInSinCerrar), las cuales saco la información de estas del siguiente Objeto :

```
 CheckIn= { "data": {
    "checkInError": [
        {
            "date": {
                "day": "2022/06/18",
                "hour": "20:41"
            },
            "transactionCode": "AWSL6xCxVM",
            "amount": 80,
            "_id": 65165161
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "day": "2022/06/19",
                "hour": "07:50"
            },
            "transactionCode": "VZz8xD6EJZQZ",
            "amount": 80,
            "_id": 65616465
        },

        {
            "date": {
                "day": "2022/08/22",
                "hour": "16:25"
            },
            "transactionCode": "L3YASDSWZJE8A",
            "amount": 100,
            "_id": 465148659
        }
    ],

    "checkInSinCerrar": [
        {
            "date": {
                "day": "2022/06/29",
                "hour": "12:23"
            },
            "transactionCode": "VYAASDSOVPF7H",
            "amount": 75,
            "_id": 58796464
        },
     
    ]
}} `
```

me gustaría saber, como se pueden acceder a los valores del objeto "**checkInSinCerrar**" y "**checkInError**" de forma correcta?, eh probado con :

```
{[checkIn.checkInError].map((check) => (
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="row">{check?.transactionCode }</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
```

tambien de esta forma :

```
    const checkInSinCerrar = CheckIn.checkInSinCerrar
checkInSinCerrar.map((check) => (
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">{check?.day}</td> </tr>))
```

También he probado con el Object.keys-values-entries

Agradecería mucho la ayuda con esto..

Comment: Te falta anteponer el data. Tu objeto tiene un padre antes de los arrays. Sería CheckIn.data.checkInError.map(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segun la estructura que tienes como estas asignando el objeto a CheckIn.

en esta pagina si necesitas ver un objeto, te puede servir posteriormente
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

lo estás haciendo bien, solo que antes debes pasar por data, según la estructura del objeto que tienes.

```
//para el primer objeto seria
CheckIn.data.checkInError.map((check) => ( //y aquí continuas con tu lógica
introducir el código aquí
//para el segundo objeto seria...
CheckIn.data.checkInSinCerrar.map((check) => ( //y aquí continuas...
```

ya te recomendaría adicionalmente que hicieras validaciones de si son variables con valor ya que el map te puede generar error, por aquí te dejo una sencilla.

```
CheckIn?.data?.checkInError?.map((check) => (
```

que tengas buena tarde.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ah servido mucho :)